# How to develop an app for a smartphone to access a web app?

Tags: browser-compatibility

My colleague developed an internal web application. This app works only in Internet Explorer, which means that I can't access it from my smartphone.

Is there any way to develop an application which will serve as a bridge between my smartphone and this web app, enabling me to use the web app from any other browser/mobile device?

Comment: That depends, what exactly is stopping it from working in other browsers? Does it use ActiveX? Does it have explicit check for IE? Some other reason?

Comment: I just want to know the concept of creating an app for accessing a website , for example we have a lot of third party apps tat are developed for logging in into our Facebook account right ,something like tat

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

You are attempting to find a technical solution to a human problem.

What you should do is to **make pressure on your colleague to modify the web application to be W3C compliant and work with normal browsers**.

Searching for workarounds would only make the problem grow: the web app would remain unusable outside IE, while growing over time, constantly hurting your company.

- What if one day your company hires a person with a disability who can't use the app through IE?
- What if Microsoft releases a version of IE which will break the compatibility with your app?
- What if the person currently developing the web app leaves the company? Who would enjoy maintaining a web app which doesn't even care being compatible with any browser?

You (your company) lock yourself in a proprietary solution, and the worst one available on the market of browsers.

This is a mistake made by many companies a decade ago. The consequences were that those companies were not able to upgrade from IE 6 to anything else, and so would force their employees to use exclusively IE 6, forbidding any other browser.

Comment: To add to your 2nd bullet -- Internet Explorer 11 does not eve identify itself as Internet Explorer in a traditional way. This breaks some of Microsoft's own product experiences.

Comment: Omg!! Ok how exactly is it possible to develop an app that supports login to an another site? For example we have a lot of third party apps for Facebook and gmail right ?

Comment: @user108351: Are you talking about SSO?

Comment: I wouldn't even take seriously anyone that nowadays has the guts to develop a IE-only web application.

Comment: @MainMa, just a simple app tat will direct me to the database of a website

Comment: @user108351: Direct you to the database of a website? What?! The website *is* what should be used to access the data in the database. If you want to do it programmatically from a smartphone app, then you should create a (RESTful) API.

Comment: @MainMa , sorry just started programming , can you tell more about the application programming interface if you don't mind? Thanks

Comment: @user108351: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service are a good start. If there are precise points you don't understand, feel free to ask an additional question on Stack Overflow or Programmers.SE.